# Passwords and Keys AKA Seahorse, how do I export private and public key pair?

Tags: 14.04, seahorse, veracrypt

I was hoping this feature has changed in the past 4 years.... I see discussions from 2012 about it.

I had to do a reinstall of Ubuntu 14, before that, I did a backup, which ended up being totally useless, but as a plan B, I exported my keys to an encrypted file with Veracrypt. Well now the bad news, that export only sent out the public keys, and the private keys are lost, with everything else lost with the unrecoverable backup.

HOW DO I EXPORT BOTH PRIVATE AND PUBLIC KEYS? or do I just have to make my keypair somehwere else, save them on an USB and import to seahorse? this is pretty convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

You can't export them both at the same time, from what I've seen. I exported my private key by pressing the "export secret key" button inside of SeaHorse (double click your key, go under the "Details" tab, then you should see the button) and exported my public key using the command "gpg --output "My Public Key.asc" --export -a " in the terminal. Your key ID is shown in the top left of "Details" tab which I mentioned earlier.